# df.timestamp.dt.date.unique() seems not working

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the dataframe:

```
                timestamp    open    high     low   close   volume
0     2023-01-03 09:30:00  3.5000  3.5800  3.5000  3.5300   1595.0
1     2023-01-03 09:35:00  3.5800  3.5800  3.5800  3.5800    102.0
2     2023-01-03 09:40:00  3.5972  3.5972  3.5972  3.5972    103.0
3     2023-01-03 09:50:00  3.5500  3.5700  3.5000  3.5200   3032.0
4     2023-01-03 09:55:00  3.4100  3.5900  3.4100  3.5900   2205.0
...                   ...     ...     ...     ...     ...      ...
1245  2023-02-21 19:35:00  6.7100  6.7200  6.7100  6.7200    739.0
1246  2023-02-21 19:40:00  6.7200  6.7300  6.7200  6.7300   2243.0
1247  2023-02-21 19:45:00  6.7300  6.7300  6.7000  6.7000   1412.0
1248  2023-02-21 19:50:00  6.7100  6.7400  6.7000  6.7400   4082.0
1249  2023-02-21 19:55:00  6.7400  6.8500  6.6500  6.7200  23678.0

[1250 rows x 6 columns]
```

I want to extract all the date, but the dataframe does not allow me.
How can I extract all the date uniquely? I tried `dt` to `df.timestamp` and `df['timestamp'].timestamp`, but it is not an attribute. I know the difference between a dataframe and a serie, but now I am hopeless

I tried to use `df.timestamp.dt.date.unique()`, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df["timestamp"]=pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])
```

#this turns your timestamps into datetime64 format

```
df["timestamp"].dt.date.unique().astype("str")
```

#this gives you a all unique values in your timestamp column and returns them as string. `dt.date` formats your timestamp into date only format without time.

Comment: You understand there is the hour as well. I just want the unique date without the hours

Comment: Sorry, but we have to remove the hours. I just need the unique date (day, month and year)

Comment: check my update. maybe that helps

Comment: No, it does not work. Here is the error:  `Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

Comment: Your timestampt have not been turned into datetimes yet. Check code above again.